# Tan() Returns Wrong Value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to calculate angle between three points and I need to use the Tangent function `tan()`. The weird thing is that VBA return wrong value.

for example:

> tan(209) = 0.554309051

but in VBA:

> tan(209) = -.696695985548265

My friend told me about something called "Normalize". but I didn't understand what he's talking about and how to do it. Why is this happening?

Comment: @Marc B: no, checked it ;-) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28209%29&a=TrigRD_R

Comment: Thats how I call tan > MsgBox Math.Tan((A(2) - B(2)) / (B(1) - A(1)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/tan.php) VBA uses radians.
Convert degrees into radians , ( degrees * 2 * pi) / 360

```
tan((209 * 2 * 3.14)/360)
```

Comment: It works but still I dont understand how u figured it out. the reference u gave explain nothing to me...

Comment: See this article on [Radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radians). Radians are a different unit of measuring angles instead of degrees. pi/2 radians is equal to 90 degrees, pi radians is equal to 180 degrees, etc.

Comment: I knew that tangent give me the angle in radian and inorder to get in in degrees I need to multiple by 180/pi. but I still dont get why my Real-Life calculator give me the right value and using the tan() function of vba gives me the wrong value

Comment: @Ron: Most likely your calculator is set to calculate with degree instead of radians. Check your calculator options.

Comment: I can't believe nobody else is pointing out the following: Tangent does *not* give an angle in radians! Arctangent does! This physicist is outraged.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to confusing radians and degrees, I think you may be confusing [tangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent) and [arctangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctangent).

In a comment, you say you call `Tan` like this: `Math.Tan((A(2) - B(2)) / (B(1) - A(1)))`. That is a very atypical way to be supplying an angle argument to a tangent! And in another comment, you imply that you expect this to give you an angle (EDIT: or "radians"). But tangent won't give you an angle or "radians"!

I can't believe nobody else is pointing this out. This physicist is outraged.

Based on this, I believe that **what you really want is arctangent**, i.e. `Math.Atn((A(2) - B(2)) / (B(1) - A(1)))`. That will give you an angle (in radians) when supplied the length ratio of the opposite to adjacent sides.

Of course, the above is largely speculative, because I don't know what you really are trying to accomplish, but from what I can tease out of the bits of implicit information sprinkled across your question and comments, that is indeed what I would put my money on.

Comment: I know that tangle doesnt give the angle, it gives radians. in order to get the angle I need to multiple the tangent by 180/pi.

Comment: OMG No!! Tangent does *not* give radians! And multiplying it by 180°/π will *not* give an angle! (save in very exceptional applications) I urge you to study the [definition of tangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent). And I'd bet my keyboard and mouse that what you really need is arctangent, the reciprocal of tangent.

Answer (score 1):

(not addressing if using TAN is correct or not):

Perhaps your cell is formated in some special way and it's changing the value.
In Excel 2007, both the worksheet funcion and VBA return **-11.8641847236695** for **tan(209).** That's different from what you have above.

Answer (score 0):

It appears VB is like Excel where is assumes the input value for Tangent is in radians. If it is not in radians, you need to convert angles in degrees to radians.

In Excel, you have to use the RADIANS() function to convert your data from angles to radians. Use the DEGREES() function to convert back.