# VBA Calculate angle relative to graph

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

In the last week I tried to calculate angle between three points - 
first I needed to get the points = easy
than to calculate the angle (not relatively) = easy too

and now I need to get the angle relative to the graph - the problem is that I dont know how (I am sure this is easy too).

PI = 3.141592654
A(2004,227)
B(2005,18)
C(2006,25)

Here's the function/formula to calculate the Angle >

```
arctan((Xb - Xa)/(Ya - Yb)) * (180/PI) + arctan((Xc - Xb)/(Yc - Yb))  * (180/PI)
```

What do I need to add to the formula so it will be relatively to the graph? (I want an explanation too please)

Here's the graph:
[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: So you're just looking to put the angle on the graph? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: I got the angle but the value is wrong because the proportion of the X Scale to Y Scale is 1 to 50.

Comment: See? I [told you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180478/vba-tan-return-wrong-value/7181701#7181701) you needed arctangent `Atn` and not tangent `Tan`! If you have any decency you will upvote that answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180478/vba-tan-return-wrong-value/7181701#7181701

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** : Here is the full code of my sub to compute it.

```
Public Sub Question()

Dim Pi As Double
Pi = 3.141592654
Dim myChart As ChartObject

For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Dim xLength As Double
    Dim yLength As Double
    xLength = myChart.Chart.Axes(1).MaximumScale - myChart.Chart.Axes(1).MinimumScale
    yLength = myChart.Chart.Axes(2).MaximumScale - myChart.Chart.Axes(2).MinimumScale

    xLength = xLength / myChart.Chart.PlotArea.Width
    yLength = yLength / myChart.Chart.PlotArea.Height

    Dim goodScale As Double
    goodScale = xLength / yLength

    Dim v1x As Double
    Dim v1y As Double
    Dim v2x As Double
    Dim v2y As Double
    Dim Angle As Double

    v1x = 2005 - 2004
    v1y = 18 - 227

    v2x = 2006 - 2005
    v2y = 25 - 18

    v1y = v1y * goodScale
    v2y = v2y * goodScale

    Angle = (Atn(v2x / v2y) - Atn(v1x / v1y)) * (180 / Pi)
Next
End Sub
```

You'll notice I hardcoded the points in the sub, but that's just to have a small self-sufficient code.

Comment: The problem is that: I take the scale from the Chart itself - u can see 50,100,150,200,250 and thefore I decided that the scale is 1 to 50. I am not sure if this is right... I have the same points on other Y scale (200) and angle looks the same but If I multiple by 200 the value is different..

plus you need to multiple the X not the Y.

Comment: Based on your calculation the proporation is 0... xlength = 2006 - 2004 = 2, ylength = 250-0 = 250, width = 667, height = 495
xlength = 2/667 = 1/333.5, ylength = 250/495 = 0.505 > scale = (1/333.5)/0.505 = 400/67367......

Comment: Based on "Me taking a measuring tape to the screen", a unit of the x axis is *about* 5cm and a unit of the y axis is *about* 0.04cm, which is a 0.008 ratio. 400/67367 ~= 0.006. I don't think it's too off, considering the approximations.

Comment: What *could* be wrong, and I'm not sure, is that I'm not sure if PlotArea.Width/Height is only the drawable area or not.

Comment: PlotArea is the graph itself, without the axes and without the rest - the real important part of the chart. and about the scale - you think ur calculation is right? then whats the angle in the picture based on your calculation? (it must be obtuse angle) [the width of the plotarea is 667 and the height is 495]

Comment: With how I defined v1(x and y) and v2(x and y), instead of Atan + aTan, you must substract one from another. See my last edit for my full code (which gives me a 122 degree angle, but I used my width/height, not the one you provided)

Comment: You just changed the intergers to doubles.. where's the full code here?

Comment: There it is! I was just editing the full post :-P  I do a for each, but you don't want to do this either, it was just to get the graph of my excel file. If you want, I can send you the whole file by email.

Comment: I see, I was doing something wrong all the time. In my real-life I tired to solve it on paper and I forgot to do Atn(v2x / v2y), I automaticly did Atn(v2y) [because the v2x is always 1 here]. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What if `v1y=0` or `v2y=0`? Better to use `Worksheetfunction.Atan2` or even better, a VBA equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117265/does-vba-have-an-atan2-function